# Array Absurdity Challenge

Tags: java

So, I have been working on the following codeeval challenge problem.

Array Absurdity

Description:

Imagine we have an immutable array of size N which we know to be filled with integers ranging from 0 to N-2, inclusive. Suppose we know that the array contains exactly one duplicated entry and that duplicate appears exactly twice. Find the duplicated entry. (For bonus points, ensure your solution has constant space and time proportional to N)

Input sample:

Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename. Each line in this file is one test case. Ignore all empty lines. Each line begins with a positive integer(N) i.e. the size of the array, then a semicolon followed by a comma separated list of positive numbers ranging from 0 to N-2, inclusive. i.e eg.

```
5;0,1,2,3,0
20;0,1,10,3,2,4,5,7,6,8,11,9,15,12,13,4,16,18,17,14
```

Output sample:

Print out the duplicated entry, each one on a new line eg

```
0
4
```

Submit your solution in a file (some file name).(py| c| cpp| rb| pl| php| tcl| clj| js) | array_absurdity.java or use the online editor.

I find it rather easy. I coded it, tested it with various test cases on my computer and it seems to be working fine. But when I submit the problem on codeveal i keep getting a 0. I have thought of all possible test cases but idk why it keeps failing. I would appreciate if you guys could give some ideas. The following solution I coded is in java.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array_absurdity {

    public static int findDuplicate(int [] arr){
        int sumAll = 0;
        int sumEle = sumElements(arr.length-2);

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            sumAll += arr[i];           
        }
        if(sumAll < sumEle)
            return 0;
        else            

        return (sumAll - sumEle);
    }
    public static int sumElements (int length){
        /*
        if(length == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return length + sumElements(length - 1);
         */
        return length* (length + 1)/2;
    }

    static String[][] readNumbers (String fileName)
    {
        String [][] arr;
        try {

            LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new FileReader (fileName));  
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                String input = scanner.next();
                stringList.add(input);
            }

            Iterator<String> iter = stringList.iterator();
            arr = new String [stringList.size()][];

            int i = 0;
            while(iter.hasNext()){

                arr[i] = new String[2];
                try{
                    arr[i] = iter.next().split(";");
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println (e);
                    System.exit (0);                    
                }
                i++;
            }

            // Done.
            return arr;
        }


        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println (e);
            System.exit (0);
            return null;
        }
        catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
            System.out.println (e);
            System.exit (0);    
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] argv){
        int [] iArr;
        String [] ele;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = sc.nextLine();
        String [][] arr = readNumbers (filename);
        int size = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){ 

            try{
                ele = arr[i][1].split(",");
                size = Integer.parseInt(arr[i][0]);
                iArr = new int[ele.length];

                if(size == iArr.length){                    
                    int duplicate = 0;
                    for (int j=0; j < ele.length; j++) {
                        iArr[j] = Integer.parseInt(ele[j]);
                        duplicate = findDuplicate(iArr);
                    }               

                    System.out.println(duplicate);
                }
            }
            catch( ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
                System.out.println (e);
                System.exit (0);    
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println (e);
                System.exit (0);            
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

A shorter version in Java.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    for (String line; ((line = br.readLine()) != null); ) {
        String[] parts = line.split(";")[1].split(",");
        int num = (parts.length - 2) * (parts.length - 1) / 2;
        for (String part : parts) num -= Integer.parseInt(part);
        System.out.println(-num);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's neat. Thanks. But Logic is not my problem, i think it's either failing because it can't read the correct file path or it's failing for some end case. But, this is definitely a neater version!

Comment: can you explain a bit with that calculation of int num and how that works?

Answer (score 6):

> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.

Your program looks like it reads the filename from System.in instead of from the command line.   It does nothing with the command-line arguments.

I haven't looked carefully at the rest of the code, but this seems to be something that might disqualify it even if the logic of the primary problem is correct.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it's just missing that key requirement. Try replacing `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); String filename = sc.nextLine(); String [][] arr = readNumbers (filename);` with `String [][] arr = readNumbers (argv[1]);`.

Comment: Thanks, trying. will let you know in a few, but seems like this is where the problem is :)

Comment: Great!  Upvotes and accepts welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic way to do it in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open FILE, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
local $| = 1;
local $, = '';

while (<FILE>) {
    $_ =~ /(\d+);(.*)/;
    my $len = $1;
    my @nums = sort split /,/, $2;
    for(0 .. $len) {
        print $nums[$_], "\n" and last if $nums[$_] == $nums[$_ + 1];
    }
}
```